# A method to get specific exports when using <script src="">

Tags: html, cdn, preact

I'm making a site with Preact & Tailwind. In the code here (I know it doesn't have head, body, e.t,c but that isn't relevant to the code):

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss-jit-cdn"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/preact/10.11.2/preact.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/htm/3.1.1/htm.js"></script>
<script>
htm.bind(h)
let component = htm`<p>Hello World</p>`

</script>
```

htm and h are parts of the Preact and HTM cdn. How do I get htm and h from the preact/htm cdns?
I don't want to use a node_modules, as i want it to be a copypastable template html to use anywhere, like WordPress, replit, codepen, e.t.c. I also don't want to use  as the way my code is setup it would look weird and bad to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a dependency (or dependencies) via `<script>` adds those to the global scope. `h`, in the example above, is undefined as you have not specified where it comes from.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss-jit-cdn"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/preact/10.11.2/preact.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/htm/3.1.1/htm.js"></script>
<script>
    let html = htm.bind(preact.h)
    let component = html`<p>Hello World</p>`
</script>
```

(Adjusted code, as `htm.bind` alone will not work. Need to assign & use the result).

This, however, is less than ideal in the modern age of ESM. Messing with globals is just rather unnecessary. Instead, use the following:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss-jit-cdn"></script>
<script type="module">
    import { h } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/preact';
    import htm from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/htm';

    let html = htm.bind(h);
    let component = html`<p>Hello World</p>`;
</script>
```

Or, even better yet, use [`htm/preact` export to skip manually binding altogether](https://github.com/developit/htm#usage):

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss-jit-cdn"></script>
<script type="module">
    import { html } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/htm/preact';
    let component = html`<p>Hello World</p>`;
</script>
```

Unpkg has a number of issues (very difficult to fix, if not impossible. Not a criticism, unpkg was built in a different time) regarding ESM usage, specifically for Preact, resolving `package.json` `"exports"` and sometimes duping the Preact instance. This is an issue for hooks, as they require a singleton by design. This is why I'd recommend Skypack or esm.sh. They're built for ESM and work brilliantly.

Comment: +1, but can I use htm/preact/standalone.module.js (which is basically bundled preact and htm?) Or do I have to use 2 imports

Comment: Absolutely, can do. `htm/preact/standalone` is actually `htm` + `preact` + `preact/hooks`, which might be even more useful for you. Here's an example REPL that I host (and use a lot): https://esm.rschristian.dev